# How to set a custom color to folded highlighting in .vimrc (for use with putty)

Tags: vim, putty, vim-syntax-highlighting

Adding the following to `.vimrc` works

```
:hi Folded ctermbg=Grey
```

but it's still too bright and prominent, so we want to specify a more specific color triplet instead, like so:

```
:hi Folded ctermbg=#A0A0A0
```

but vi won't accept it:

```
Error detected while processing /home/guest/.vimrc:
line   10:
E421: Color name or number not recognized: ctermbg=#A0A0A0
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The `cterm` in `ctermbg` is short for "color terminal". It is used to define the background color when Vim runs in a terminal emulator and can only accept named colors like `grey` or `cyan` or color numbers like `7`. Hexadecimal values only work in GVim/MacVim and must be used with `guibg`/`guifg` like that:

```
hi Folded guibg=#A0A0A0
```

In your shell, do `$ echo $TERM`: it should return something like `xterm`, `screen`, `xterm-256color` or some variants.

If you run Vim in a terminal emulator that can't display more than 8/16 colors (`$TERM` doesn't contain `256color`), you won't be able to use a different shade of grey unless you define your own palette in your terminal emulator.

It should look like this:

```
hi Folded ctermbg=7
```

or like that:

```
hi Folded ctermbg=grey
```

If your terminal emulator advertises itself as "256 colors ready" (`$TERM` contains `256color`), you are able to use any color in [this chart](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Xterm_256color_chart.svg) as long as you use its number (`242`) and not its hexadecimal value.

It should look like this:

```
hi Folded ctermbg=242
```

Comment: echo $TERM results in "xterm", and I have PuTTY configured to use xterm 256 color mode. When I try Color 216 (Peach), it appears as black in PuTTY. Do I need to do something such that $TERM will result in xterm256 or 256color? Thanks

Comment: `TERM` is defined at the terminal emulator level: if you have configured PuTTY to use `xterm-256color` and you get `xterm` then something is messing with you.

Comment: looks like xterm/xterm-256color/256color (assigned to $TERM) are just arbitrary strings that can be configured in PuTTY. Found the solution in http://www.mediabandit.co.uk/blog/151_putty-colours. Anyway thanks for the lead

Comment: Is it also possible to set "no color"? I'm trying to remove visible BG from the folded line, blending it with others (highlighted line no. is enough for me).  When I set 16, the color is black which does not fit every term's scheme, and 0 or not setting it results in grey.

Comment: @AloisMahdal, `ctermbg=NONE guibg=NONE`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl)'s explanation, the following lines must be added to .vimrc as described [here](http://www.mediabandit.co.uk/blog/151_putty-colours):

```
if &term =~ "xterm"
  "256 color --
  let &t_Co=256
  " restore screen after quitting
  set t_ti=ESC7ESC[rESC[?47h t_te=ESC[?47lESC8
  if has("terminfo")
    let &t_Sf="\ESC[3%p1%dm"
    let &t_Sb="\ESC[4%p1%dm"
  else
    let &t_Sf="\ESC[3%dm"
    let &t_Sb="\ESC[4%dm"
  endif
endif
```

After which any decimal color value chosen from the [xterm256 color table](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/15/Xterm_256color_chart.svg) provided by [romainl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/546861/romainl) should display in PuTTY accordingly.

Comment: adding just **set t_Co=256** to .vimrc is also enough.